# launch lamson as a process

Tags: python, smtp, lamson

Can I programmatically launch the lamson SMTP server from inside my python code?

it cam be launched from the command line as:

```
lamson start
```

but , I want to launch it from code using the multiprocess package

```
from multiprocessing import Process

   def f(name):
      # what to put here

if __name__ == '__main__':
   p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
   p.start()
   p.join()
```

what to put in the f function to lauch a lamson server

How this can be achieved?

thanks